# Write string to file in lisp

Tags: file-io, lisp, common-lisp

I ran some code like this

```
(defun writeFile (name content)
    (with-open-file (stream name
        :direction :output
        :if-exists :overwrite
        :if-does-not-exist :create)
    (format stream content)))
(writeFile "C:\Users\Peter\test.txt" "Test...")
```

but then I checked my `C:\Users\Peter` directory and it did not contain create a file named `test.txt`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try this: `(writeFile "C:\\Users\\Peter\\test.txt" "Test...")`

Comment: Also, it's strange that you don't get something like `The path #P"C:UsersPetertest.txt" does not exist`.

Comment: @htbta `C:\Users\Matthias> copy con c:UsersPetertest.txt`, `Hi.`, `^Z`  => `1 file(s) copied.`

Comment: @Matthias Benkard so `C:foo` is equivalent to `C:\foo` on Windows? Then it's ok.

Comment: @htbta It actually means “file `foo` in the current working directory on drive `C`.”  On Windows, each drive has its own current working directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\` is an escape character in strings in Common Lisp.

`(length "\\")` is `1`.

`(length "\U")` is `1`.

`"\U"` is `"U"`.

`"C:\Users\Peter\test.txt"` is `"C:UsersPetertest.txt"`.

So you are writing a file called `"C:UsersPetertest.txt"`.

Three possible solutions:

- escape the backslash with a backslash
- I'm not sure if that works: use a forward slash
- use one of the PATHNAME functions to construct the pathname

Advanced: use a logical pathname